# How to edit website using Cyberduck

Tags: html, cyberduck

I have uploaded my website by Cyberduck. However, now I want to make some changes. I did edit it in the host but when I access the website through my domain, id didn't change anything.

I don't know whether I did something wrong or the changes need take time.

Comment: this could be a plethora of things.  does your host use caching?  are you editing the files you think you are? are you uploading the files where you think you are?  there are too many variables for us to be able to help you.

Comment: it's correctly because of cache. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it would be cached somewhere. Try opening your website in incognito mode (Chrome), I ain't sure what it's called on other browsers & see if you see the updated content on website.

Comment: @ĐăngHòaNguyễn Glad that it worked for you. You can click on "tick" icon to mark your question as solved.